# Tooltip en html

Tags: php, html, css

Estoy tratando de insertar un tooltip dentro de una tabla en html pero parece irse al fondo y no queda visible.

Script con un version resumida de mi problema:

-http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.as3EC7S5WUCK

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. ¿Qué utilidad tendrá tu pregunta cuando el enlace deje de estar disponible? Como la respuesta es "_ninguna_", te recomiendo editar tu pregunta de tal forma que el enlace pase a ser algo complementario o accesorio. Piensa que las preguntas que realizas pueden acabar beneficiando a más usuarios si se escriben con cierto criterio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Has probado utilizar la etiqueta `title` de HTML por cada `td` para utilizar el "tooltip" que viene por defecto en HTML?

Ejemplo:

```
<td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="PASSED" title="Texto tooltip"> PASSED </td>
```